# Azure Servicebus queue delay in receiving ordered messages

Tags: azure, .net-core, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Using an Azure ServiceBus Queue with sessions (message-ordering) enabled,  I have sessions that need to last between a couple of minutes and a couple of hours.

To that end, I have configured my QueueClient as follows:

```
_options = new SessionHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
{
    AutoComplete = false,
    MaxConcurrentSessions = 50,
    MessageWaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
};
```

and start receving messages as follows:

```
_queueClient.RegisterSessionHandler(ProcessSessionMessagesAsync, _options);
```

After a few (between 1 and 6) successful (and near instantaneous) message-receive callbacks -- both for new sessions and existing ones, **the receive handler just stops firing**. Using `ServiceBusExplorer`, I can see messages sitting on the servicebus queue. Interestingly, they all have a **DeliveryCount=1**. 
After some time (this varies between a few seconds and a few minutes -- but not a multiple of MessageWaitTimeout), I start receiving a trickle of messages again. If I restart the receiver, then I sometimes get a burst of all remaining messages, sometimes nothing more.

I've tried various values for `MessageWaitTimeout`, and although lower values seem to lessen the issue, the delays still exist.

Interesting, if I complete sessions after *every* message received, the problem still persists.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? The behavior is so infuriatingly inconsistent...

FWIW, my `messageReceivedHander` looks something like this:

```
async Task ProcessSessionMessagesAsync(IMessageSession session, Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        var myEvent = Serializer.Deserialize(message.Body);
        await _receiveCallback(Subscription, myEvent);
        await session.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

        // Drop the session after every message (**makes no difference**)
        await session.CloseAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await session.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was in fact me being an idiot.

The _receiveCallback() was actually a call out to an external service (requestbin), which was throttling my messages under load and causing the behaviour I was experiencing. When I stubbed that out, I saw consistent (and fast) behvaiour.

Answer (score 0):

Just some suggestions:

1. Do not close asession in ProcessSessionMessagesAsync.

   <del>await session.CloseAsync();</del>
2. As you just registered a handler, so please make your application alive to make sure that all the tasks will be finished. For example: you can end your application after a Console.Readline().

I run the official sample: [BasicSessionSendReceiveUsingQueueClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/BasicSessionSendReceiveUsingQueueClient/Program.cs), it works fine. You can have a try.

Comment: Thanks Jack; I mentioned that the CloseAsync makes absolutely no difference.
I'm tried running this in as a BackgroundService (IHostedService), and I've also stripped out the logic into a Console app -- and although the issues lessened, I still saw some occurrences. 
I'm seeing _some_ sort of correlation to CPU usage -- this FEELS like a race condition in the QueueClient's Message pump, but I know better than to assume it's not my code :).